# 2x TB from MBPr to display PBP on 4k monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, displayport

I have MBPr 13" early 2013, as it does not support 4k at 60Hz, I was wondering if I can use both TB ports (max TB resolution is 2560x1600) to push image to a 4k display using picture by picture functionality? I would flip them vertically.

Any experience with this idea?

Backup plan is to pick up two 2560x1440 monitors :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Picture by picture does work, but window snapping to screen disables you from using the centre of the screen. Test the setup if you are thinking about it.

I went with dual QHD screens and it works great. Also, the internal screen can be driven along them without any problem/